# Assigning EventListener in a loop

Tags: javascript

I use this line of code to add an event listener to my div's that are created through a forloop:

```
for(var i in mail){
   //create div
   parent.addEventListener("click",function(){read_msg(mail[i].id);},false);
   //append to parent
}
```

This is causing the problem of `mail[i].id` being the last id for all of them. I've read some examples of how to solve it but i find it still very confusing.

I was suggested the solution of :

```
(function(){read_msg(mail[this].id)}).bind(i);
```

But am told this is not a great solution to use, was hoping someone could explain how you get `read_msg` to hold the correct value of `id` ? It always seems a bit messy in terms of a solution.

Comment: "But am told this is not a great solution to use" --- any details? "Not great" is not a great explanation

Comment: That solution is fine.

Comment: @zerkms thats the point of the question why the solution is no good? I was not told anything more.

Comment: @Dave: never trust anything proven technically :-)

Comment: The solution is good, that's the point of these comments.

Comment: It may be "not great" enough for browsers that don't support `.bind()`

Comment: @zerkms: True but easily polyfillable (if that's a word).

Comment: @elclanrs: I call that "shim" ;-) and see the second part about several parameters I've added after your comment has already been added

Comment: @zerkms: Why is no good for several parameters?

Comment: @elclanrs: oh I see - I didn't know `bind()` accepts them, I thought it only allows to define a scope. Then I was wrong

Comment: @zerkms: Built-in currying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using a closure variable `i` in your event handler function.

The variable `i` resides in the scope of the outer function, ie there is only one instance of the variable `i`. When the handler method is called and `i` is accessed javascript will look at the scope of the handler function first, if it does not find the variable there it will look at the parent closure scopes, then it will find the variable in the parent scope.

In the parent scope the value keep changing the value of `i` as the loop is executing that is why all the callback have the same value for `i`.

The solution here is to create a local closure

```
for(var i in mail){
    (function(myvar){
        parent.addEventListener("click",function(){read_msg(mail[myvar].id);},false);
        //append to parent
    })(i);
}
```

Here what we does is we have a Immediately Invoked Function Expression, to which we are passing the value of `i` as parameter `myvar`. So each iteration in the loop will create a independent closure.

Comment: So what is the correct solution or maybe thats not the right term but a solution that is usually considered best practice?

Comment: Event delegation is better. Look it up. Basically you look for the click event on the container with all the elements in that mail collection. Events bubble to their parents (unless you stop them), but you can still get the target element with the event object. It's also handy for elements that get added after you set the event. There's crossbrowser hijinx with ie < 9 though.

Comment: @Dave It's an option. I don't think using `.bind()` to set the `this` value is right, because normally with event handlers, the value of `this` is set as the element...I know you're just calling `read_msg` and passing the specific item according to the loop, but as a general solution, you should use something *like* this answer. This answer obviously gets the job done, but I find it messy. You could easily create a new function that "generates" a function that captures that value from the loop

Comment: @Ian you mean another function that returns the handler method right, in terms of what happens it is the same, syntactical differences that is all

Comment: @Ian are you referring to dan's suggestion?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Absolutely, they both do the same thing. I just find it messy to have to create an IIFE in a loop. It just seems "better" to separate these things. I know I've suggested the IIFE in past SO answers, so I'm contradicting myself, but I've become accustomed to calling a function instead

Answer (score 1):

you can use Object+Array methods in most browsers to side-step the pesky loop scope "bug" in js:

```
 function addClick(key){
   //create div
   parent.addEventListener("click",function(){read_msg(mail[key].id);},false);
   //append to parent
}   

Object.keys(mail).forEach(addClick);
```

since functions have scope and forEach eats functions, you don't need the extra anon wrapper when you use Array methods.

if you want to go all out new JS hotness:

```
 function addClick(key){

   parent.addEventListener("click", this.method.bind( this.elm, this.source[key].id ), false);

}   

Object.keys(mail).forEach(addClick, {elm:parent, source: mail, method:read_msg });
```

where you invert the source object of the key to allow using objects other than "mail", elements other than "parent" to attach events upon, and methods other than "read_msg", all without having to touch the logic or use the word "return"... Basically, whatever you setup in the traditional C-style for-loop initializer, you move to this.something and re-apply the logic as the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

because each anonymous function you define as an event handler with each loop iteration will share the same scope as all the others, they will all reference the same var (i) as the array address for the message you are trying to display. Because your are redefining the var i with each loop, you will always see the last message in your message array displayed on each click event because the last value assigned to i will have been the length of your "mail" array.

heres how to fix it:

```
var helper = function(index) {
    parent.addEventListener("click", function(){read_msg(mail[index].id);},false);
}

for(var i in mail) {
    helper(i);
}
```